# Sorry, Component JACLPlus has been installed UNSUCCESSFULLY?

Tags: php, joomla, jacl

I am using joomla 1.0.13 and i am trying to access JACLplus but this error is occuring and i dont know why? it was running fine and all of a sudden now it is saying this?

Sorry, Component JACLPlus has been installed UNSUCCESSFULLY

i have never used joomla and have inherited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else, your version of Joomla is way out of date. The current version is 1.5.22. You should look at upgrading.

As for the error, can you see JACL in the backend of the website? Looks like it's been uninstalled but not all of the files have been removed.

Comment: I cant upgrade due to other reasons. When i log into joomla administration and go to the menu jacl plus option from the drop down under components. I dont want it uninstalled? any idea how to get it back to how it was

Comment: All the files are there on the backend on the server, nothing has been altered

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Depending on your host you might need to FTP and change the file permissions and try reinstalling it.

Comment: Any idea how i start to try re install it? the permissions on all the folders of the site are fine

Comment: Uninstall and then reinstall. You'll need to download the latest version. Make sure you backup the database first!